# Faster OpenCV remap

Tags: c++, opencv, remap

I am using remap function to undistort openCV image in C++ as following

```
remap(srcImg, dstImg, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

It takes a lot of time.

Is there is a way I can increase its speed? I tried using Intel remap but did not know how to using with openCV image.

Comment: [mre] is required. quantify "a lot of time". size of input, size of maps, time to execute, what computing platform, ... -- generate the maps to be in the fixed point (integer) format, not floating point.